# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name application, locale en_US

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

i have the following config class in spring boot application contenerized in docker:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"file:${application.properties}"})
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({
       
        ConfigurationFiltreSecurite.class
})
public class ApplicationConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


}
```

and in the context-app.xml file i have the following parameter

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Context configuration file for my web application -->
<Context path="/app-backend" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/app-backend.war" antiResourceLocking="true">
    <Parameter name="application.properties" value="/app/ml/awd/config/application-app.yml"/>

/>
```

here is my docker compose file :

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  tomcat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.tomcat
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"
      - "SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION=file:/app/ml/awd/config/"
```

but when i run the docker-compose up of the contenerized tomcat i have the following error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to 
instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw 
exception; nested exception is java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle 
for base name application, locale en_US
tomcat_1
```

Comment: Why the complexity? If it is Spring Boot why are you deploying to a containerized Tomcat instead of using the embedded tomcat, as that is only complicating things. Just use the embedded container, ditch the `@PropertySource` and `@EnableWebMvc` (as that will disable parts of Spring Boot). And provide `--spring.config.additional-location=/app/ml/awd/config/application-app.yml` in the command to start the application. Or as `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION` docker environment variable.

Comment: Reason for the deployment being complex is that you are deploying to a dockerized tomcat instead of using an embedded Spring Boot one. Your configuration doesn't really help in making things easier as well (basically you are working around much of what Spring Boot offers).

Comment: Please don't add code in comments as that is totally unreadable.

Comment: this is the requierement , it does not work when adding : --spring.config.additional-location=/app/ml/awd/config/application-app.yml

Comment: I even doubt it is related to that as it comes from setting up the `springSecurityFilterChain`. So it probably hardcoded tries to load something. ALso make sure to remove the `@PropertySource` (as mentioned before) and the `@EnableWebMvc`. I would however simplify your deployment by ditching the tomcat and use the Spring Boot embedded tomcat instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum propertySource works when giving the parameter to the war in context.xml , and point to it with ${}